# Redefine \chapter and \chapter* with \cleardoublepage inside .cls-file

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

```
\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{{\let\cleardoublepage\relax\chapter{#1}}}
```

works fine. How can I do the same for the stared (*) version inside a .cls-file?

(Could be interesting for others: Is there any difference to defining it in the main document?)

Comment: You are not redefining `\chapter`, `\Chapter` is a just wrapper command. Are you sure, that your `\cleardoublepage` is not `\relax`ed for ever? Other issue: What about `\chapter[short]{long}`?

Comment: What's your base class? Many classes (`report`, `book`, `memoir`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook` know option `openany`. Then chapters can also start on even pages. This option would make the "chapter" hack of the question obsolete.

Comment: @ Heiko: I know. I use scrbook. I want the cleardoublepage normally and want to disable it just once.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: At least in my case, the relax works only for that very one chapter. Haven't thought about \chapter[short]{long}, yet.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sorry, I'm new to StackExchange. I just ticked the accept mark to my other questions. Anything else, I'm doing wrong? I thought, I had read everything. :-/

Comment: @doublerainbow64: No, no, it's just appreciating the work done by other ones! Go ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have indicated that you wanted to redefine `\chapter` and `\chapter*`. For this I suggest to take a look at a deeper level in your class and it's no beginners' task.

You could anyway build a macro which has incorporated a starred version and uses the command `\chapter` written in your class.

A very basic way goes as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand{\MyChapter}{%
    \let\cleardoublepage\empty
    \clearpage
    \chapter
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\MyChapter{Introduction}
some text

\MyChapter[My Introduction]{Introduction}
some text

\MyChapter*{Introduction}
some text

\end{document}
```

The command `\MyChapter` erases `\cleardoublepage`, it executes `\clearpage` and `\chapter`. It will have all of your old `\chapter`'s features, because `\chapter` is executed last and takes as arguments whatever you put after `\MyChapter`.

However the latter **is NOT a good practice**, since command `\cleardoublepage` is rendered useless, and erasing latex commands can often cause bad functioning.

IMHO a "decent" practice could be saving `\cleardoublepage` and restoring it later:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand{\ResCdp}{%
    \let\cleardoublepage\cdp
}

\newcommand{\MyChapter}{%
    \let\cdp\cleardoublepage
    \let\cleardoublepage\empty
    \clearpage
    \chapter
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\MyChapter{Introduction}\ResCdp
some text

\MyChapter[My Introduction]{Introduction}\ResCdp
some text

\cleardoublepage

\MyChapter*{Introduction}\ResCdp
some text

\end{document}
```

which is somewhat difficult to read/write but does the trick safely.

To avoid using this `\ResCdp` without erasing `\cleardoublepage` and keeping all `\chapter`'s features would take many more efforts.

Comment: That's, I think, a good solution. Still, not perfect, as you would have to invoke the `\ResCdp` manually after each use of `\MyChapter` and it would of course be very comfortable to include this into the new command, but this seems to be very difficult. I'll accept this as an answer to my question.

Comment: The most difficult part is that `\chapter` uses a lot of different commands written in the class to achieve `scrbook`'s goals.As a fact, each command is often used inside of others, and usually we cannot change one of them without affecting the rest of them. I never took a look inside `scrbook.cls` nor used it, but for instance with the `book` class you can achieve your goal redefining a sub command named `\@chapter`, which is not available at user level (as implied by the use of `@` in the command sequence name). Doing this is no big deal. Big deal is knowledge and training. So keep it up! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have indicated that you use the `scrbook` document class. If you want to redefine `\chapter` (and `\chapter*`) to execute `\clearpage` instead of `\cleardoublepage`, I suggest you load the `etoolbox` package and use its `\patchcmd` macro to modify the `chapter` macro:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}{}{}
```

Comment: I tried this a lot of time -- it will fail, as far as I know, due the special way this kind of commands are defined

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm getting it wrong, but... even if it were working, wouldn't that add `\cleardoublepage` rather than remove it?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Thanks for this. I've updated the answer. The code works with the `book` and `scrbook` classes.

Comment: @doublerainbow64 - Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - By the way, I'm a fan of your blog (especially the bon mots by teacher "H.").

Comment: @Mico: Well, thanks... that unknown guy "H." will add some bon mots, the new term has just started ;-)

Comment: @Mico: Thank you, but I think, this doesn't solve the issue. As I said, the actual problem is about the stared version, but this doesn't seem to work with the method you provided in your answer. In addition, I'm not trying to overwrite any command, but to create a new one for usage without the `\cleardoublepage`. Actually, it can easily be accomplished using `\newcommand{\ChapterStaredVersion}`, but I thought, using the star for my new command the same way as for the normal command would be nicer.

Comment: @Mico: Added two old bon mots ;-)

Comment: @doublerainbow64 - The patch works for both starred and unstarred chapters. By the way, I doubt it's a good idea to have some chapters perform `\clearpage` while others perform `\cleardoublepage` -- choose one or the other for your document.

Comment: @Mico: I'm very sorry, you're right. The patch is applied to both, stared and not-stared version. Apart from that: I appreciate your recommendation concerning the styling of my doc. I agree that 'normal' docs should open on odd pages only. However, I insist on this different approach in my specific case. I suppose, I will simply use the option `openany` and insert additional `\cleardoublepage`s manually.

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure, but the package `etoolbox` says that one needs the exact same category code regime as in the original definition (since the command is retokenized). So you could add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to be safe. Unless I misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: @Manuel - I don't think it's necessary to use the `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` wrappers in the present case: the command being patched and the characters being replaced contain only "letter-type" (cat. 11) tokens -- No `@` symbol to make things "interesting" as far I can tell. :-)

Comment: @Mico I know, it's just a thing I usually do to avoid (in some case) problems. In case someone at some point has a problem, that might be the problem (the problem is bigger with `\ExplSyntax…` since that one changes many catcodes).

Answer (score 0):

In case of `scrbook` use option `openany` and insert `\cleardoublepage`s manually.

It's not exactly the answer to the question, still, I decided to use this method.

Comment: The question is not well posed; if your aim is opening chapter on either even or odd pages, the *correct* method is issuing the `openany` option.

Comment: My intention was to somehow define new commands, one including the `\cleardoublepage` and one using `\clearpage` only. It does not really matter, whether you create a new command to omit the `\cleardoublepage` or use option `openany` and create a new command using an additional `\cleardoublepage`.
The question was about how to define the stared version of `\chapter`. Since the insert of a `\cleardoublepage` is certainly not as disturbing as the `\let...\relax` command, I decided that I can live without a macro for this. However, the question about how to define one remains unanswered to me.